# Input focus go to wrong window after switching language in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04, input-language

When I change the language with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, input focus goes to terminal. What should I do to fix this?

**Edit:**

This problem only happens when the terminal window is ***Always on top*** mode.

Comment: Can you try changing the shortcut for input method, and report back if the issue persists?

Comment: Yes, I change the shortcut and still have the same issue. @ArchismanPanigrahi